# How to call native C code, using the js-ctypes Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, c, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I am trying to build a Firefox extension, that needs to call native C code.

My C program code is:

```
#include<windows.h>
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return(a + b);
}
```

and my JavaScript code is :

```
var {Cu} = require('chrome');
var self  = require('sdk/self');
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
var lib;
var puts;
lib = ctypes.open('G:\\Shankar\\Project\\Maidsafe\\Firefox\\addon-sdk-1.17\\jsctype_sample\\data\\Win32Project1.dll');

try {
    puts = lib.declare("add", /* function name */
        ctypes.default_abi, /* call ABI */
        ctypes.int32_t, /* return type */
        ctypes.int32_t, /* argument type */
        ctypes.int32_t /* argument type */
    );
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Érror'+ e);
}

function binaryFile() {        
    var ret = puts(1, 2);
    dump(ret);
    lib.close();
};

exports.binaryFile = binaryFile;
```

when calling the `binaryFile` function, I get the error

```
Couldn't find function symbol in library
```

Please help me out.
tHanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't yout use `int` instead of `int32_t`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my [repository](https://github.com/shankar2105/Firefox_addon_sdk_jsctypes) where complete code is been available

Answer (score 5):

If your addon is a restartless addon, make sure to set `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>`. The addon MUST be unpacked.

Awesome, you're getting deep into addons! See this repo: https://github.com/Noitidart/fx-sapi-test That shows the code to main.cpp which is compiled into a DLL and then imported and used.

You have to expose your `add` function.

By the way, if you were doing a bootstrap addon: Also try doing the `ctypes.open` inside the `startup()` function. But you aren't, you're doing an Addon SDK addon, so you should be ok. But for your import do this:

```
lib = ctypes.open(self.data.url('Win32Project1.dll'));
```

That way you don't have to know the absolute path. Especially because `\\` file seperator is only for Windows. Unix like systems (MacOSX, Linux, ...) use `/`.

If you need more help join the moz jsctypes IRC channel :)

- https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsctypes
- irc://moznet/jsctypes

Comment: Cheers for the shared links! Did help me it getting my stuff sorted :) Will connect on the channel with you to learn more on the Add-on. Have been breaking my head a lot more with XPCOM. Thanks again.

Comment: self.data.url('someFile.dll') in the ctypes.open give the error as couldn't open library resources://....

Comment: I myself solved it by using var dataUrl = self.data.url("udp_client.dll");
dataUrl = Services.io.newURI(dataUrl,null,null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file.path;. Thanks

Comment: Awesome job there! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This might help some one just like me. :)